# group by json object sharing key name

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class NameDTO
{
    public string Name;
}

public class ValDTO
{
    public string Val;
}

_nameDetials = new List<NameDTO>();
_valDetials = new List<ValDTO>();
```

Into List _nameDetials I get keys and into _valDetails I get values for which I used below for block and added them to array. In my given values below i get count as 20 into each of the lists.

```
JArray jChildArray = new JArray();      

for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(_nameDetials.Count, _valDetials.Count); i++)
{
    JObject jChildObject = new JObject();    
    jChildObject.Add(_nameDetials[i].Name, _valDetials[i].Val);    
    jChildArray.Add(jChildObject);                                                  
}
```

I have a json array as shown below

```
[
  {
    "message-Code": "   0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos1": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos2": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos3": " "
  },
  {
    "message-Code": "   0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos1": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos2": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos3": " "
  },
  {
    "message-Code": "   0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos1": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos2": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos3": " "
  },
  {
    "message-Code": "   0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos1": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos2": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos3": " "
  },
  {
    "message-Code": "   0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos1": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos2": "0"
  },
  {
    "msg-Number-Pos3": "0"
  }
]
```

I want to group this data to get the result as shown below.

```
[
    {
      "message-Code": "  0",
      "msg-Number-Pos1": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos2": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos3": "0"
    },
    {
      "message-Code": "  0",
      "msg-Number-Pos1": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos2": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos3": "0"
    },
    {
      "message-Code": "  0",
      "msg-Number-Pos1": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos2": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos3": "0"
    },
    {
      "message-Code": "  0",
      "msg-Number-Pos1": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos2": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos3": "0"
    },
    {
      "message-Code": "  0",
      "msg-Number-Pos1": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos2": "0",
      "msg-Number-Pos3": "0"
    }
]
```

I want to group based on same key names.

I tried the below code

```
var grouparray = (from t in jChildArray
                  group t by new { t }
                  into grp
                  select grp.Key.t).ToList();
```

I am unable to trace what is that I am missing.Or can we group a json array into equal number i.e. 4 in my case.
I am new to c# and unable to find a matching code.
Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Use something like `group t by t.messageCode`  and `select grp`

Comment: What is the algorithm that groups the first array into the second one? I can't find any pattern connecting both sets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not want to group by the key but rather by number of items. Can you try:

```
    private string Serialize(List<NameDTO> _nameDetials, List<ValDTO> _valDetials)
    {
        JArray jChildArray = new JArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(_nameDetials.Count, _valDetials.Count) / 4; i++)
        {
            var jChildObject = new JObject();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                jChildObject.Add(_nameDetials[i * 4 + j].Name, _valDetials[i * 4 + j].Val);
            jChildArray.Add(jChildObject);
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jChildArray);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo. You made my day. That 4 is coming from config file, so no need to bother about that since it is a dynamic value.